# Alternative approach to clearing graphics

Tags: c++, graphics

i have been using **cleardevice()** to clear the graphics ...   but it creates several problems

for eg .. i create a background but i have to clear some specific elements , then i have to use another user defined function ***drawb(***) which draws the background and simultaneously **cleardevice();**
creating a lot of problems

```
line(x,y,x1,y1);   //suppose this line is to be erased 
                   //but using cleardevice even clears the background   
cleardevice();
drawb();  //to draw board or background
```

so i want to know an alternative approach(an approach to clear only the line not the background) (if it exists )

Comment: What graphics library are you using? And why do you need `cleardevice()` if you draw the background straight after? Doesn't drawing the background over the entire screen qualify as a clear? You should look at clipping if you want to clear a specific area.

Comment: i think i need to make the situation clear

Comment: i dont know correctly about the library .... but i am using turboc++.. ( i know its outdated) .. but my school uses so) ..so most probably winbgim

Comment: it uses bgi graphics for sure @BenRuijl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a line is drawn, there is no real way to remove it (except if you are drawing using [XOR mode](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setwritemode.html)!). However, there are some thing you could do. You could render everything but the line in a page and store it there. Then, in another page you render everything, including the line. So if you want to undo the line, you just switch the page back.

An example:

```
setactivepage(0);
// draw stuff, including background
setactivepage(1);
// draw stuff, including background and line
setvisualpage(0); // no line visible
setvisualpage(1); // line visible
```

Also, if you want to reset the screen with a background, there is no need to do a `cleardevice()`, since the `drawb()` overwrites every pixel ayway.

Answer (score 1):

You can first take the image before drawing the line by `getimage()`
and put that image on the line whenever you want to hide your image
 This will not change your background and not flick it. `putimage()` can put the image.