# How to display text using delays?

Tags: c++, graphics, delay

How can I display text while erasing the older text?

```
init();
check()
{
    outtextxy(5,20,"hello")
    delay(500),
    outtextxy(5,20,"bye") 
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234515/alternative-approach-to-clearing-graphics

Comment: what platform, language, gfx API, gfx mode ..?

Comment: windows,c++,turbo c++,bgi